# json nmp package not working

Tags: json, npm

I am using json npm package to update package.json file.

Using following commands

```
json -f package.json -I -e this.dependencies.data-version=\"1.0.0.1\"
```

Getting following error message

```
undefined:2
this.dependencies.'data-version'="1.0.0.1"
                  ^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected string
    at new Function (<anonymous>)
    at main (C:\Users\SEUser2\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json\lib\json.js:
1289:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\SEUser2\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jso
n\lib\json.js:1683:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
```

I observer that if field name contains '-' character if creates issue.

How to run above command escaping '-' character ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I've found to update outdated packages in the `package.json` is to use: [npm-check](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check)
`npm-check -u`
Which will let you interactively update the packages you want to update.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using this.dependencies['data=version'] instead

Comment: I have tried this:  json -f package.json -I -e this.dependencies['data-version=\"1.0.0.1\"']. Its not working.